# Add animation to State machine in SpriteKit Error

Tags: sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

Hi guys am trying to add this animation to my game state am getting this error

override func didEnterWithPreviousState(previousState: GKState?) {

```
    Ninja_Run = self.childNodeWithName("Ninja_Run") as! SKSpriteNode //ERROR HERE:RunningState' has no member 'childNodeWithName'
    var frames: [SKTexture] = []
    for i in 0 ..< 9 {
        let tex:SKTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Run__00\(i).png")
        frames.append(tex)
    }
    Ninja_Run!.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(frames, timePerFrame: 0.055)))
    Ninja_Run!.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error describes, the [GKState](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GKState_Class/) class doesn't have any member functions called `childNodeWithName`.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to reference **GameScene** file

**Replace:**

```
Ninja_Run = self.childNodeWithName("Ninja_Run") as! SKSpriteNode
```

**With:**

```
let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") //Or everywhere is your sprite
Ninja_Run = scene.childNodeWithName("Ninja_Run") as! SKSpriteNode
```

Comment: Thanks @Simone Pistecchia. Much appreciated.